# a Loop on cells in excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel

i am not a pro in C#, I'm still learning and i just wanted a loop that checks if the cell is empty then write in it by a windows form
for example

```
while (true)
        {
            object i = 2;

            if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2 == null)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2 = textBox2.Text;
                break;
            }
            else     
                i++;
        }
```

i can't increment an object and to select a cell i have to use this data type
So is there any replace for this loop

Comment: it should be int i =2 and it should be outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
int count = 2; 
 while (true)
    {
        object i = count;

        if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2 == null)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value2 = textBox2.Text;
            break;
        }
        else     
            count++;
    }
```